How to improve new Context-close vote proposal?
I really like the ideas behind Robin's answer to this question, but I feel like it could use a bit of polish. Since it's kind of unwieldy to continue discussing that post in the comments, I've created a new question.
Given the goals of a Close Vote reason:

Can the title of the reason be improved? The current proposed title is "Below quality standards".
Can the body of the reason be improved? The current body is: 


This question does not meet the quality standards, and it is unlikely
  to receive a satisfying answer. The question shows no attempt of
  initial research and/or shows no relevance to CogSci.SE. Let the
  readers know at what level you expect an answer, and show them why
  they would want to answer it? The more context you provide, the better
  we'll be able to answer your question.


What should the FAQ linked to the reason contain? A good close reason should link to an FAQ if it's not covered adequately in "How to Ask".


Based off of my thought process contained in this MindMap, I propose the following modifications.
Change the title to have less overlap  with other close-vote reasons
Below Quality Standards is too similar to the other close-vote reasons. Consequently, I propose changing the title to either Insufficient motivation or Insufficient context.
Shorten the description and add actions
The current description is a bit long to be appended to every question that gets closed. It also doesn't mention potential actions for OP soon enough. Here is the alternative I suggest:

This questions provides insufficient Cognitive Science specific
context to be satisfyingly answered. Please modify your question
according to this FAQ. Currently, the question shows no
initial research and/or relevance to CogSci.SE.

The content for the FAQ should elaborate on the following

Tips for improving the question, such as:

What level of answer do you expect?
Why would someone want to answer your question?


The FAQ should also emphasise that the more context you provided, the better we'll be able to answer your question.

I agree, +1. I would go for "insufficient context".

Btw, to explain my "below quality standards" name. I initially also called the reason "no context" but thought that a more general name would better. But, given your explanation, it is indeed better to be more specific, because it (including the body of reason) was awefully close to "unclear what you're asking"
